# Git: How to ensure new branch is based on upstream master

Tags: git, github, branch

I've been making a lot of rookie mistakes with github and as a result I'm seeking a foolproof (me-proof!) method for ensuring that:

a) All new branches I create on a fork are based on origin master, not some other branch, and...

b) That my origin master is always up-to-date with upstream master, and...

c) That when/before I commit (push?), my changes are rebased to upstream master.

Here's what I have so far...

To create new branch:

```
git fetch --all --tag
git pull upstream master
git push origin master
git checkout -b my_branch_name -t origin/master
```

To store my changes to that branch:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Summary of what changed"
git fetch --all --tag
git pull --rebase upstream master
git push origin my_branch_name
```

To load an existing branch at a later date (eg. to do some additional changes resulting from PR feedback):

```
git fetch --all --tag
git pull upstream master
git push origin master
git checkout my_branch_name -t origin/master
```

And then to save my updates to that branch:

```
git add -A
git commit --amend --no-edit
git fetch --all --tag
git pull --rebase upstream master
git push origin my_branch_name -f
```

I must confess I don't fully comprehend what some of these commands do - there seems to be lots of ways to do lots of similar sounding things and despite lots of googling/reading I'm still a rookie.

Any guidance very much appreciated!

Comment: `git pull --rebase upstream master` followed by `git push origin my_branch_name` won't work in general, because you are rewriting the history of `my_branch_name`.  Instead, you would have to force push your branch via `git push --force origin my_branch_name`.

Comment: Can you narrow down your question to be more specific?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The most vital thing I'm seeking is how to ensure any new branch I create (or existing branch I open) is based on master and not some other branch. That's where the biggest pain is for me, I keep somehow making branches that are based on previous branch rather than master.

Comment: This is a common mistake, I do it myself still even after years of using Git.  Just checkout `master` and do your `git branch` from there, it's really that simple.

Comment: Will the `checkout master` be the most recent upstream master? (for some reason my origin master always seems to get out of sync with upstream master)

Answer (score 17):

after setting upstream

```
git checkout -b branch-name
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
git push --set-upstream origin branch-name
```

Comment: if there is no upstream, try this:
git remote add upstream YourUpstreamUrl

Answer (score 6):

If `upstream master` refers to the latest master branch in the server/remote, you could simply run the following cmd to create a new branch.

```
git fetch origin master
git checkout -b <new_branch> FETCH_HEAD
```

If you don't mind working on detached HEAD, you could also run

```
git fetch origin master
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 3):

To create a feature branch based on the "current" `master` branch, you should take the following steps:

```
git checkout master                # switches to your local master branch
git pull origin master             # updates remote tracking branch, merges into local master
git checkout -b my_feature_branch  # create a new branch from your updated local master
```

Note that there is always the possibility that new changes keep coming into the remote `master` branch on GitHub.  Actually, you should generally assume that this will be happening, and you need to deal with it via merging or rebasing.

Answer (score 3):

If you have changes in the downstream master you want to keep, I would do the following to keep the downstream master the same but create a new branch on the upstream master.

```
git checkout -b upstream-master
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
git push --set-upstream origin upstream-master
```

Comment: I believe it should be `git reset` instead of `revert` in line 3, like in Jiburiru's answer.